# Socket connects, crashes and reconnects

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

so I have my client-server program which was working fine, but now I ran into an issue and I have not a single clue on how to solve it. So my client connects to the server, using async sockets. But when it tries to get the async result, it contains nothing. It disposes the socket and starts all over. This is my code(client):

```
public class Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs as a result of an unrecoverable issue with the client.
    /// </summary>
    public event ClientFailEventHandler ClientFail;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a method that will handle failure of the client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The client that has failed.</param>
    /// <param name="ex">The exception containing information about the cause of the client's failure.</param>
    public delegate void ClientFailEventHandler(Client s, Exception ex);

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires an event that informs subscribers that the client has failed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex">The exception containing information about the cause of the client's failure.</param>
    private void OnClientFail(Exception ex)
    {
        var handler = ClientFail;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the state of the client has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event ClientStateEventHandler ClientState;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method that will handle a change in the client's state
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The client which changed its state.</param>
    /// <param name="connected">The new connection state of the client.</param>
    public delegate void ClientStateEventHandler(Client s, bool connected);

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires an event that informs subscribers that the state of the client has changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connected">The new connection state of the client.</param>
    private void OnClientState(bool connected)
    {
        if (Connected == connected) return;

        Connected = connected;

        var handler = ClientState;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, connected);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a packet is received from the server.
    /// </summary>
    public event ClientReadEventHandler ClientRead;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a method that will handle a packet from the server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The client that has received the packet.</param>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet that has been received by the server.</param>
    public delegate void ClientReadEventHandler(Client s, IPacket packet);

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires an event that informs subscribers that a packet has been received by the server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet that has been received by the server.</param>
    private void OnClientRead(IPacket packet)
    {
        var handler = ClientRead;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, packet);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a packet is sent by the client.
    /// </summary>
    public event ClientWriteEventHandler ClientWrite;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the method that will handle the sent packet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The client that has sent the packet.</param>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet that has been sent by the client.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The length of the packet.</param>
    /// <param name="rawData">The packet in raw bytes.</param>
    public delegate void ClientWriteEventHandler(Client s, IPacket packet, long length, byte[] rawData);

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires an event that informs subscribers that the client has sent a packet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet that has been sent by the client.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The length of the packet.</param>
    /// <param name="rawData">The packet in raw bytes.</param>
    private void OnClientWrite(IPacket packet, long length, byte[] rawData)
    {
        var handler = ClientWrite;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, packet, length, rawData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the packet received.
    /// </summary>
    public enum ReceiveType
    {
        Header,
        Payload
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The buffer size for receiving data in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    public int BUFFER_SIZE { get { return 1024 * 16; } } // 16KB

    /// <summary>
    /// The keep-alive time in ms.
    /// </summary>
    public uint KEEP_ALIVE_TIME { get { return 25000; } } // 25s

    /// <summary>
    /// The keep-alive interval in ms.
    /// </summary>
    public uint KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL { get { return 25000; } } // 25s

    /// <summary>
    /// The header size in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    public int HEADER_SIZE { get { return 4; } } // 4B

    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum size of a packet in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    public int MAX_PACKET_SIZE { get { return (1024 * 1024) * 5; } } // 5MB

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an array containing all of the proxy clients of this client.
    /// </summary>
    public ReverseProxyClient[] ProxyClients
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_proxyClientsLock)
            {
                return _proxyClients.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle of the Client Socket.
    /// </summary>
    private Socket _handle;

    /// <summary>
    /// A list of all the connected proxy clients that this client holds.
    /// </summary>
    private List<ReverseProxyClient> _proxyClients;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock object for the list of proxy clients.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _proxyClientsLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The buffer for incoming packets.
    /// </summary>
    private byte[] _readBuffer;

    /// <summary>
    /// The buffer for the client's incoming payload.
    /// </summary>
    private byte[] _payloadBuffer;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Queue which holds buffers to send.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Queue<byte[]> _sendBuffers = new Queue<byte[]>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the client is currently sending packets.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _sendingPackets;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock object for the sending packets boolean.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _sendingPacketsLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The Queue which holds buffers to read.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Queue<byte[]> _readBuffers = new Queue<byte[]>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the client is currently reading packets.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _readingPackets;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lock object for the reading packets boolean.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly object _readingPacketsLock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The temporary header to store parts of the header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This temporary header is used when we have i.e.
    /// only 2 bytes left to read from the buffer but need more
    /// which can only be read in the next Receive callback
    /// </remarks>
    private byte[] _tempHeader;

    /// <summary>
    /// Decides if we need to append bytes to the header.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _appendHeader;

    // Receive info
    private int _readOffset;
    private int _writeOffset;
    private int _tempHeaderOffset;
    private int _readableDataLen;
    private int _payloadLen;
    private ReceiveType _receiveState = ReceiveType.Header;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets if the client is currently connected to a server.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Connected { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The packet serializer.
    /// </summary>
    protected Serializer Serializer { get; set; }

    private const bool encryptionEnabled = true;
    private const bool compressionEnabled = true;

    protected Client()
    {
        _proxyClients = new List<ReverseProxyClient>();
        _readBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        _tempHeader = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to connect to the specified ip address on the specified port.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ip">The ip address to connect to.</param>
    /// <param name="port">The port of the host.</param>
    protected void Connect(IPAddress ip, ushort port)
    {
        try
        {
            Disconnect();

            _handle = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _handle.SetKeepAliveEx(KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME);
            _handle.Connect(ip, port);

            if (_handle.Connected)
            {
                _handle.BeginReceive(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AsyncReceive, null);
                OnClientState(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
        }
    }

    private void AsyncReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int bytesTransferred; // error occurs here

        try
        {
            bytesTransferred = _handle.EndReceive(result);

            if (bytesTransferred <= 0)
                throw new Exception("no bytes transferred");
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Disconnect();
            return;
        }

        byte[] received = new byte[bytesTransferred];

        try
        {
            Array.Copy(_readBuffer, received, received.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
            return;
        }

        lock (_readBuffers)
        {
            _readBuffers.Enqueue(received);
        }

        lock (_readingPacketsLock)
        {
            if (!_readingPackets)
            {
                _readingPackets = true;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncReceive);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            _handle.BeginReceive(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AsyncReceive, null);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
        }
    }

    private void AsyncReceive(object state)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] readBuffer;
            lock (_readBuffers)
            {
                if (_readBuffers.Count == 0)
                {
                    lock (_readingPacketsLock)
                    {
                        _readingPackets = false;
                    }
                    return;
                }

                readBuffer = _readBuffers.Dequeue();
            }

            _readableDataLen += readBuffer.Length;
            bool process = true;
            while (process)
            {
                switch (_receiveState)
                {
                    case ReceiveType.Header:
                        {
                            if (_readableDataLen + _tempHeaderOffset >= HEADER_SIZE)
                            { // we can read the header
                                int headerLength = (_appendHeader)
                                    ? HEADER_SIZE - _tempHeaderOffset
                                    : HEADER_SIZE;

                                try
                                {
                                    if (_appendHeader)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            Array.Copy(readBuffer, _readOffset, _tempHeader, _tempHeaderOffset,
                                                headerLength);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            process = false;
                                            OnClientFail(ex);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        _payloadLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(_tempHeader, 0);
                                        _tempHeaderOffset = 0;
                                        _appendHeader = false;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        _payloadLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(readBuffer, _readOffset);
                                    }

                                    if (_payloadLen <= 0 || _payloadLen > MAX_PACKET_SIZE)
                                        throw new Exception("invalid header");
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    process = false;
                                    Disconnect();
                                    break;
                                }

                                _readableDataLen -= headerLength;
                                _readOffset += headerLength;
                                _receiveState = ReceiveType.Payload;
                            }
                            else // _readableDataLen < HEADER_SIZE
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Array.Copy(readBuffer, _readOffset, _tempHeader, _tempHeaderOffset, _readableDataLen);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    process = false;
                                    OnClientFail(ex);
                                    break;
                                }
                                _tempHeaderOffset += _readableDataLen;
                                _appendHeader = true;
                                process = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case ReceiveType.Payload:
                        {
                            if (_payloadBuffer == null || _payloadBuffer.Length != _payloadLen)
                                _payloadBuffer = new byte[_payloadLen];

                            int length = (_writeOffset + _readableDataLen >= _payloadLen)
                                ? _payloadLen - _writeOffset
                                : _readableDataLen;

                            try
                            {
                                Array.Copy(readBuffer, _readOffset, _payloadBuffer, _writeOffset, length);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                process = false;
                                OnClientFail(ex);
                                break;
                            }

                            _writeOffset += length;
                            _readOffset += length;
                            _readableDataLen -= length;

                            if (_writeOffset == _payloadLen)
                            {
                                bool isError = _payloadBuffer.Length == 0;

                                if (!isError)
                                {
                                    if (encryptionEnabled)
                                        _payloadBuffer = AES.Decrypt(_payloadBuffer);

                                    isError = _payloadBuffer.Length == 0; // check if payload decryption failed
                                }

                                if (!isError)
                                {
                                    if (compressionEnabled)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            _payloadBuffer = SafeQuickLZ.Decompress(_payloadBuffer);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception)
                                        {
                                            process = false;
                                            Disconnect();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    isError = _payloadBuffer.Length == 0; // check if payload decompression failed
                                }

                                if (isError)
                                {
                                    process = false;
                                    Disconnect();
                                    break;
                                }

                                using (MemoryStream deserialized = new MemoryStream(_payloadBuffer))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        IPacket packet = (IPacket)Serializer.Deserialize(deserialized);

                                        OnClientRead(packet);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        process = false;
                                        OnClientFail(ex);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                _receiveState = ReceiveType.Header;
                                _payloadBuffer = null;
                                _payloadLen = 0;
                                _writeOffset = 0;
                            }

                            if (_readableDataLen == 0)
                                process = false;

                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            if (_receiveState == ReceiveType.Header)
            {
                _writeOffset = 0; // prepare for next packet
            }
            _readOffset = 0;
            _readableDataLen = 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a packet to the connected server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the packet.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet to be send.</param>
    public void Send<T>(T packet) where T : IPacket
    {
        if (!Connected || packet == null) return;

        lock (_sendBuffers)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    Serializer.Serialize(ms, packet);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnClientFail(ex);
                    return;
                }

                byte[] payload = ms.ToArray();

                _sendBuffers.Enqueue(payload);

                OnClientWrite(packet, payload.LongLength, payload);

                lock (_sendingPacketsLock)
                {
                    if (_sendingPackets) return;

                    _sendingPackets = true;
                }
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Send);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a packet to the connected server.
    /// Blocks the thread until all packets have been sent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the packet.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="packet">The packet to be send.</param>
    public void SendBlocking<T>(T packet) where T : IPacket
    {
        Send(packet);
        while (_sendingPackets)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void Send(object state)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!Connected)
            {
                SendCleanup(true);
                return;
            }

            byte[] payload;
            lock (_sendBuffers)
            {
                if (_sendBuffers.Count == 0)
                {
                    SendCleanup();
                    return;
                }

                payload = _sendBuffers.Dequeue();
            }

            try
            {
                _handle.Send(BuildPacket(payload));
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnClientFail(ex);
                SendCleanup(true);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] BuildPacket(byte[] payload)
    {
        if (compressionEnabled)
            payload = SafeQuickLZ.Compress(payload);

        if (encryptionEnabled)
            payload = AES.Encrypt(payload);

        byte[] packet = new byte[payload.Length + HEADER_SIZE];
        Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(payload.Length), packet, HEADER_SIZE);
        Array.Copy(payload, 0, packet, HEADER_SIZE, payload.Length);
        return packet;
    }

    private void SendCleanup(bool clear = false)
    {
        lock (_sendingPacketsLock)
        {
            _sendingPackets = false;
        }

        if (!clear) return;

        lock (_sendBuffers)
        {
            _sendBuffers.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disconnect the client from the server, disconnect all proxies that
    /// are held by this client, and dispose of other resources associated
    /// with this client.
    /// </summary>
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_handle != null)
        {
            _handle.Close();
            _handle = null;
            _readOffset = 0;
            _writeOffset = 0;
            _tempHeaderOffset = 0;
            _readableDataLen = 0;
            _payloadLen = 0;
            _payloadBuffer = null;
            _receiveState = ReceiveType.Header;

            if (_proxyClients != null)
            {
                lock (_proxyClientsLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (ReverseProxyClient proxy in _proxyClients)
                            proxy.Disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Commands.CommandHandler.StreamCodec != null)
            {
                Commands.CommandHandler.StreamCodec.Dispose();
                Commands.CommandHandler.StreamCodec = null;
            }
        }

        OnClientState(false);
    }

    public void ConnectReverseProxy(ReverseProxyConnect command)
    {
        lock (_proxyClientsLock)
        {
            _proxyClients.Add(new ReverseProxyClient(command, this));
        }
    }

    public ReverseProxyClient GetReverseProxyByConnectionId(int connectionId)
    {
        lock (_proxyClientsLock)
        {
            return _proxyClients.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ConnectionId == connectionId);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveProxyClient(int connectionId)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_proxyClientsLock)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _proxyClients.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_proxyClients[i].ConnectionId == connectionId)
                    {
                        _proxyClients.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

The output from visual studio:

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
Client Fail - Exception Message: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4782
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe
Client Fail - Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe
```

The refuse was because the server wasnt running, when I start the server and it connects the crsahing loop begins

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you change the IP address?   You cannot have both the listener and the client both use the same 3 IP parameters 1) Source IP address 2) Destnation IP address 3) Port number.   So normally the listener to IPAny and the client connects to the IP address of the PC which you can get using cmd.exe >IPConfig/all.  Sometimes a process get stuck open and you make have to manuall kill the process using Control Panel.  To see if port is still open use cmd.exe >Netstat -a.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that. But I have been able to run them both on the same machine, they both worked perfectly untill now

Comment: Impossible.  You cannot have two connections on the same PC with Source IP, Destination IP, and port number being the same.  When you connect two application on the same PC you have two connections with the PC operating system forwarding the data between the two connections.  There is a host file in the windows system32\drivers\etc folder that defines local.host.  Which is sometimes set to the IP of PC and sometimes set to 127.0.0.1 (loopback).  The Net Library often gives errors when you use loopback in the connect method().  So I usually use the IP in the Connect method of client.

Comment: I'll run it in a vm, maybe that works. Will report back, thanks

Comment: I had no luck, same error. When checking, it calls the AsyncCallback, but in the IAsyncResult the AsyncResult is null for some reason

Comment: Change the client from 127.0.0.1 to the IP address of the PC.

Comment: Same issue.....

Comment: You may have a process running from previous testing the didn't close.  You could reboot PC.  First check from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if you have a TCP connection running with the port number you are using.

Comment: Tried that too, for some reason it keeps returning a null AsyncState

Comment: The server must be started first.  So there could be something wrong with the server.

Comment: Tried that too, some issue

Comment: What error message are you getting now that you are NOT using 127.0.0.1.  And you are sure that no other application is using Port 4782 (check with Netstat -a).  The port could be blocked by a virus checker or firewall.  Try a port number above 10000.

Comment: Tried, no succes. No antivirus or firewall running

Comment: Still didn't post error message after changing IP address.

Comment: Oh sorry i though i wrote it in the comment, its still the exact same message

Comment: How can the error be 127.0.0.1 when you changed the IP?  Check if the IP address has changed.  Use cmd.exe >ipconfig/all.  You may want to use the computer name instead of IP.  If Group Policy is being used on a network the IP address will change regularly while computer name will always be the same.

Comment: That refuse message doesnt occur when the server is running, the issue is this error: Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Client.exe on the asynccallback the socketexception was because the server didnt run

Comment: I had the same issue earlier this week.   When the client closes a connection you will get an exception in the callback in the client.  Simply add an exception handler in the callback to handle exception and make sure you do not call the BeginRead method.  The client will stop sending.

Comment: @jdweng I thank you, I found the error. Gonna add it as answer so someone else can read it when they stumble across the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, the connection thread on the client had an empty ipadress string in the code and had the hostname it used didnt exist, I should've looked better at all code. Thanks